# Going from composites to individual functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-analysis

$f(g(k(x)))=\sqrt{1+4x^2}$ and $g(k(f(x)))=1+4x$

What is a systematic way to solve for $f$,$g$,and $k$? I never learned anything like this in algebra.

Comment: I assume you want $f$, $g$, and $k$ to be elementary functions (i.e. they can be written as formulas in terms of +,-,x,/, exponents, roots, and possibly logs/trig)

Comment: yes! that is what i want

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that there is a systematic way besides the "educated guess". Looking at $ \sqrt{1 + 4x^2}$ and  $1 + 4x$
we see that the former contains the functions $\sqrt{\cdot}$ and $(\cdot)^2$, and the latter does not. As squaring and the square root are inverses to each other, two of the functions in $g\circ k \circ f$ should be $\sqrt{\cdot}$ and $(\cdot)^2$. As the square root is applied last and the squaring function first in $\sqrt{1 + 4x^2}$, we guess $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and $k(x) = x^2$. As now $(k \circ f)(x) = x$, we are left with 
$$ 1 + 4x  = (g \circ k \circ f)(x) = g\bigl(k \circ f)(x)\bigr) = g(x) $$
And now we have 
$$ f\Bigl(g\bigl(k(x)\bigr)\Bigr) = \sqrt{1 + 4x^2} $$

Comment: There has to be a systematic way. Can we try to be systematic.

Comment: Would there a be a way to make a system of equations solving for each function in terms of other functions and inverses and then "solving" a system of equations? This is really unspecific and lame but Im trying to get the ball rolling here.

Comment: @djax Perhaps an easier question would be to restrict yourself to polynomial functions? Or if there are only two functions?

Comment: Hmm so you mean to say you should have some prior knowledge of the type of function to solve it?